# Is the impossibility of integrating the reciprocal of a function connected to the limitations of algebra?

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals, mathematica

I will do two examples:

Let $$f(x)=\sum _{n=0}^{11} x^n$$

and then integrate in Mathematica:

$$\int \frac{1}{f(x)} \, dx$$

and one sees that Mathematica gives a solution.

However, let

$$f(x)=\sum _{n=0}^{12} x^n$$

and then try to integrate in Mathematica:

$$\int \frac{1}{f(x)} \, dx$$

then Mathematica gives the answer as a [RootSum](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RootSum.html)

> So therefore I ask if the integrability of the reciprocal of a
>   function is limited by the limitations of algebra?
>
> $$\int \frac{1}{f(x)} \, dx=?$$

I know almost nothing about algebra or integrals.

Comment: The indefinite integral is a rational function. This may be a limitation in mathematica, but not a limitation in algebra. Rootsum seems to be an ingredient in one way to represent rational functions. I've tagged the question with "mathematica" so someone else can provide a definitive answer.

Comment: Have a look at my edit. The problem already happens with $f(x)=1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first case $$f(x)=\sum _{n=0}^{11} x^n$$ this can be factorized as
$$f(x)=(x+1) \left(x^2+1\right) \left(x^2-x+1\right) \left(x^2+x+1\right)
   \left(x^4-x^2+1\right)$$ and partial fraction decomposition leads to
$$\frac 1{f(x)}=\frac{1-2 x}{12 \left(x^2-x+1\right)}+\frac{1-x}{6 \left(x^2+1\right)}+\frac{1}{4
   \left(x^2+x+1\right)}+\frac{x^3-x^2-2 x+2}{6 \left(x^4-x^2+1\right)}+\frac{1}{6
   (x+1)}$$ which is workable.

This is not at all the case with the second one which does not show any real root. So, let
$$f(x)=\sum _{n=0}^{12} x^n=\prod_{i=1}^{12}(x-ri)$$ and partial fraction decomposition will lead to
$$\frac 1{f(x)}=\sum_{i=1}^{12}\frac{a_i}{x-r_i}\implies \int \frac {dx}{f(x)}=\sum_{i=1}^{12}a_i\log(x-ri)$$

**Edit**

If you note $$f_n(x)=\sum _{k=0}^{n} x^k$$ and try to compute (using a CAS)
$$\int \frac{dx}{f_n(x)}$$ you should notice that, for $0 \leq n \leq 20$, you would get explicit results for $n=0,1,2,3,5,7,11,15$. For all other values, you will get the answer in terms of *RootSum* as you called it.

Comment: The first one only has a single real root. That's not really a requirement or prerequisite in any way.